# Overlapping viewports with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency, viewport

I'm trying to make a camera (gui camera) render above the scene camera. My ideia was to set the gui camera to have a transparent background, and so it would be possible to see through it, but it is not working as I expected.

I defined the renderer like:

```js
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

And I am trying to render like so:

```js
// Render Main Camera
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
renderer.render(scene, sceneCamera);

// Render GUI Camera
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
renderer.render(scene, guiCamera);
```

I used this https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_views.html as an example for multiple viewports but it's different since their viewports aren't overlapping.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `renderer.autoClear = false;`. You may have to call `renderer.clear()` manually, and set `scissor` to limit what is cleared.

Comment: I tried messing with those (except the scissor, as I don't quite understand what it does) but it didn't really workout, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment. By default three will clear your frame buffer before you call `.render()`. So if you call it several times the effect would be as if you only called the last one.

If you set `renderer.autoClear = false` you will disable this feature. If you move your camera for example you'll see streaking as your objects from different frames get painted one on top of another.

Hence calling `renderer.clear()` before your first render would allow you to paint the same frame with several `.render()` calls.

It might make sense to use something like `const guiScene = new Scene()` and put your UI objects in there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on creating a new scene for the GUI, I've used unity so I was thinking of using layers but the scene approach seems pretty cool.

Now that you've elaborated I've gotten closer to the result I wanted, and does GUI is indeed being rendered above the scene, however, the background color changes from black to white when the gui camera is being rendered.

Changing to renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1); worked, but I wonder why it didn't work since I had set opacity to 0.

Comment: Not sure if i understand the color clearing problem. If you set the alpha to 0, you shouldn't see any color, it would be fully transparent. But there could be many reasons for white showing up. If you make a fiddle it could be easier to help :)